# ng2-bootstrap Open Popover from component?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm looking at the bs-popover from the ng2-bootstrap library here:
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover.  But I don't see any example of how to open/close the popover from the component code.  Has anyone done this?  Here is my current view template:

```
<template #tipTemplate>
    <div class="row pop-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button (click)="pop.hide()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>&nbsp;Close
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <line-chart></line-chart>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" (click)="pop.show()" container="body">
            <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <span [popover]="tipTemplate"
              #pop="bs-popover"
              popoverTitle="Labs"
              placement="bottom"
              triggers=""
              class="lab-title">
            Troponin
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it's working fine, however instead of my button's click event directly opening the popover i'd like to invoke a function in my component which then does a few things and one of them is open the popover.  Is this possible with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this inside your component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

inside the component,

```
@ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;
```

and then, whenever you want to open the modal

```
 this.childModal.show();
```

Comment: well the above code is for modal, but you could use the same

Comment: thanks!, I should have realized that the same pattern would work for a popover :).